# How do I add a column to one dataframe based on a partial string match in another dataframe?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I'm trying to use one dataset to clean another dataset.

I have a data frame of (human-error) miscoded course names called `MiscodedVisits`

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  EMAIL      SemesterYear Course
  <chr>      <chr>        <chr> 
1 aap@fn.edu S16          CHM212
2 aar@fn.edu S14          PHY000
3 abc@fn.edu F17          PHY000
```

And I have a dataframe of course rosters called `Rosters`.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  EMAIL      SemesterYear Course
  <chr>      <chr>        <chr> 
1 aap@fn.edu S17          CHM212
2 aap@fn.edu S16          CHM112
3 aar@fn.edu S14          PHY222
4 abc@fn.edu F17          AST300
5 abc@fn.edu F17          MAT255
```

I want to look up the miscoded `Course` in `Rosters` (by `EMAIL` and `SemesterYear`) in order to add `CorrectedCourse` based on a partial match of the `Course` string representing the course (CHM, PHY, etc.)

The result I want would have MiscodedVisits look like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  EMAIL      SemesterYear Course CorrectedCourse
  <chr>      <chr>        <chr>  <chr>          
1 aap@fn.edu S16          CHM212 CHM112         
2 aar@fn.edu S14          PHY000 PHY222         
3 abc@fn.edu F17          PHY000 NA
```

I've tried:
A. Mutating a new column `CorrectedCourse` in `MiscodedVisits` based on a string match of `Rosters$Course`. `mutate(CorrectedCourse = DemoPerf$Course [match(EMAIL, DemoPerf$EMAIL) & match(SemesterYear, DemoPerf$SemesterYear)] )`
 Failed because of syntax `Error in match(EMAIL, DemoPerf$EMAIL) : object 'EMAIL' not found`

B. `fuzzy_inner_join (MiscodedVisits, Rosters, by= c(Course = "S\\d{2}"), match_fun = str_detect)` Error: `Error: Column`col`must be a 1d atomic vector or a list`

C. `regex_inner_join (MiscodedVisits, Rosters, by= c(Course = "S\\d{2}"))` Error: `Error: Column`col`must be a 1d atomic vector or a list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this using  `dplyr` and `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

MiscodedVisits %>% mutate(code = str_extract(Course, "[A-Z]*")) %>%
  left_join(Rosters %>% mutate(code = str_extract(Course, "[A-Z]*")), 
            by = c("EMAIL", "SemesterYear", "code")) %>% select(-code)

#       EMAIL SemesterYear Course.x Course.y
#1 aap@fn.edu          S16   CHM212   CHM112
#2 aar@fn.edu          S14   PHY000   PHY222
#3 abc@fn.edu          F17   PHY000     <NA>
```